# How to test StartChatContact API in Postman? | "Unable to determine service/operation name to be authorized"

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-connect

I am trying to start AWS connect chat from a third-party application. I have implemented **StartChatContact** in Postman, which gives a participant token that is further used in **CreateParticipantConnection**.

**StartChatContact**

[image: StartChatContact]

**Body**

```
{
   "ContactFlowId": "cd1a0465-0a02229-4a1a-9894-fb14945548264",
   "InstanceId": "84ece66549-184a-400f-babf-59888d7c8fd04",
   "ParticipantDetails": { 
      "DisplayName": "Customer"
   }
}
```

This is working fine and returns the participant token.

**CreateParticipantConnection**

[image: This is throwing error]

**Body**

```
{
   "ConnectParticipant": true,
   "Type": [ "WebSocket" ]
}
```

When I placed the token in CreateParticipantConnection, it throws an error that is mentioned below:
[image: Error]

**Error**

```
{
    "message": "Unable to determine service/operation name to be authorized"
}
```

Kindly provide me your valuable guidance. I am following [StartChatContact](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/APIReference/API_StartChatContact.html#API_StartChatContact_RequestSyntax) and [CreateParticipantConnection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect-participant/latest/APIReference/API_CreateParticipantConnection.html) documentations.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested but I believe the type needs to be "WEBSOCKET" not "WebSocket" i.e. it is case sensitive.

Comment: I have changed it but. unfortunately, the result is the same.

Comment: Odd, I've given this a go myself, can't get the exact error message you are seeing but my basic tests show that when Type is set to "WEBSOCKET" (and it definitely is case sensitive) the ConnectParticipant needs to be set to `false`. It then sends back a WebSocket ConnectionExpiry and Url.

Comment: I already tested it by setting false, the result is the same. I don't know where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Okay, so this is what is working for me...
**Start Chat** - [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5LHm.png)
**Create Participant Headers** - [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2YDw.png)
**Create Participant Body** - [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1c4Ii.png)

Are you setting the `X-Amz-Bearer` header to the Participant token?